# Python 2.7 multiprocessing with ndenumerate and function with array/function arguments

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function in 2.7 that I'd like to hopefully speed up with multiprocessing. My code is effectively a ton of 4x4 ndarrays that goes something like this.

```
import numpy as np

def randomFunction(array1, array4, val):
  # Some random function that does auxiliary task but that gets called each iteration

def mpFunction(array1, array2, ... array X, randomFunction, (i, j, k), val):
  # Code that calls things like array1[i, j, k], uses val, calls randomFunction, etc.


array1 = np.zeros((largeNumber, 4, 4), dtype='float')
array2 = np.zeros((largeNumber, 4, 4), dtype='float')
arrayX = *more 4D arrays that have actual data in them*

for (i, j, k), val in np.ndenumerate(array1):
  mpFunction(array1, array2, ... array X, randomFunction, (i, j, k), val)
```

The function is trivially parallelizable, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement this. I tried with

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

...
pool = Pool()
results = pool.map(mpFunction(array1, arary2, ... array X, randomFunction), np.ndenumerate(array1))
```

But debugging shows that I get all my functions in mpFunction but also the ndenumerate iterator, and I don't know what I should be doing with that. Any tips on how to get this to work the way I'm hoping?

Comment: What are you trying to parallelise? Right now it seems you provide a single set of input parameters to the `pool.map` call albeit in an incorrect manner. Please take an extra look at how the map function is used in the documentation https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html. For example you need to create some iterable that can be chunked to disperse amongst processes.

Comment: I thought that np.ndenumerate would be my iterable, but I subsequently realized that that's not sufficient. Turns out that list(np.ndenumerate(...)) would give my iterable (in my case, giving me an i,j,k associated with array1). I also found that it was sufficient to pass in all my arrays that weren't being iterated over as **kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't using pool.map() correctly. I needed

```
from functools import partial

my_list = list(np.ndenumerate(array1))
result = mp.pool(partial(mpFunction, ***kwargs), my_list)
```

and to actually do a `return ...` to actually pull data from my mpFunction into the real world.